# Can't resolve 'angular' error when using Angular JS component in Angular 8 Application

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am trying to use an Angular JS library in my Angular 8 app and following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-from-angularjs-to-angular-with-ngupgrade)

After exporting the js module and bootstrapping it in main.ts I get this error while compiling and have no idea what to do.

This is my angular js module (fef.forms.module.ajs.ts):

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

const MODULE_NAME = 'fef.forms';
angular.module(MODULE_NAME, ['wj', 'fef.shared']);
export default MODULE_NAME;
```

PS: It Can't resolve 'angular' in this js module.

Comment: did you upgrade your angular? to angular 8 if so the code above wont work

Comment: The main application is Angular 8 I have copied the angular js project in it

Comment: why you need angular js library if you can do it in angular 8